# Fichero diccionario para leer desde función en JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Estoy intentando crear una aplicación en js. Como entrada tendré un pequeño texto (una frase) y querría comparar algunas palabras de este texto con un diccionario que aún no tengo hecho.

Dicho diccionario querría que para cada entrada pudiese tener varios valores y, por tanto, desde una función en js leer si alguna de las palabras del texto de entrada coincide con algún valor de alguna entrada del diccionario.

Por ejemplo, si en el diccionario tuviese que la palabra "greater" tiene como valores "greater", "higher" y "bigger" y en mi texto de entrada tengo la palabra "higher", querría poder encontrar, a través de esta, la entrada del diccionario correspondiente, en este caso, "greater".

Cuál podría ser la mejor manera para implementar este diccionario?

Comment: Hi. You're in StackOverflow in Español, please translate your question 'cause it could be closed.

Comment: Pues parece que lo ideal sería usar un diccionario... o usando un sinónimo en programación, un [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Map) o tabla hash

Comment: No puedes usar una base de datos?

Comment: @PabloLozano he leído acerca de map en js, pero no he visto que permita tener varios valores para una misma clave, sino que deben ser pares. A no ser, claro, que repitiese la clave tantas veces como valores quiero asignarle

Comment: Puedes hacer eso último las veces que te haga falta, varias claves apuntando al mismo valor

Comment: @Srsole lo había pensado, pero mi conocimiento sobre ellas es muy bajo

Comment: JS no puede leer ficheros (hablando del front end), puedes usar Local storage para ello.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const dic = [
    {definition:'of considerable size or extent.',words:['bigger','higher','greater']}
]
const findDef = (word)=>{
    dic.forEach(words => {
        words.words.forEach(val=>{
            if(val===word){
                console.log(words.definition)
            }
        })
    });
}

findDef('higher')
```

Este seria un pequeño ejemplo de como podrías implementarlo, podrías usar perfectamente un map o otro método pero  este es un ejemplo usando un array con un pequeño "objeto" que pues tiene la definición de del valor ingresado y una sección de los sinónimos que podría tener esa palabra, como es una función la deberás llamar con el valor ingresado, entonces una vez tiene el parámetro se hace un forEach que recorrerá el total de definiciones que tiene tu diccionario, y dentro de esa definición buscara si la palabra ingresada esta dentro del mismo, y si coincide entonces envía la definición.

Comment: La verdad es que funciona perfectamente y es sencillo de implementar.

Comment: Muchas gracias!

Comment: Me alegra que te haya servido, y si no es molestia podrias marcarlo como  una buena respuesta?... aun asi hay muchos otros metodos muchos mas eficaces pero es solo un ejemplo de como podrias hacerlo.